# convert mysql db to php array in particular format

Tags: php

I have seen other solutions but they don't put the data in the php array the way I would like it described below.

I have a **database** called: **users**

In the database there is many **tables** e.g. **alice,bob**

Each table has the following **columns** e.g. **id,name,age**

I would like to get all that data and put it into a php array, like so:

```
Array
(
[db_users] => Array
   (
     [0] => Array
        (
          [id] => 1
          [name] => alice
          [age] => 34
        )
     [1] => Array
        (
          [id] => 2
          [name] => bob
          [age] => 42
        )
   )
)
```

Comment: WOW: Database design disaster if your description is accurate

Comment: If you saw other solutions...they all contained code. We have no idea what you tried that didn't work if you don't show us. This isn't a code writing service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have 1 table called `Users` with columns `id`, `name`, and `age` then Alice, Bob, et. al. get one row in that table. Now you have one simple query that will return the array you desire.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Users
```

Here's an example schema for MySQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE Users (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    age INT
);

INSERT INTO Users (name, age) VALUES
    ('Alice', 34),
    ('Bob',   42);
```

And here's an example using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
<?php

// returns an intance of PDO
// https://github.com/jpuck/qdbp
$pdo = require __DIR__.'/example_DhBXcw_A.pdo.php';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Users';

$array = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($array);
```

Results in this output

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [id] => 1
>             [name] => Alice
>             [age] => 34
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [id] => 2
>             [name] => Bob
>             [age] => 42
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have something to work with. **NOTE:** *I have not tested this code, it's just something you could work with.*

```
<?php
    $result = [];
    $connection = new PDO("host","dbname","username","password");

    $tables = $connection->prepare("show table"); 
    //add ' from [your database name]' to get the tables from specific db.
    $tables->execute();

    foreach($tables->fetchAll() as $table){
        $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
        $query->execute();
        //or do another foreach to do some fance stuff, no idea what this outputs. 
        array_push($result,array($table => $query->fetchAll()));
    }
?>
```